# Why composable function is calling multiple times

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DeviceListScreen(onDeviceClick: (MyDevice) -> Unit){
    Timber.tag(TAG).d("Initial composition")

    T1(onDeviceClick)
//    T1{}
//    T2("Hello world")
}

@Composable
fun T1(onDeviceClick: (MyDevice) -> Unit){}

@Composable
fun T2(text: String){
    Text(text)
}
```

My `DeviceListScreen` is calling 4 times. If I comment line `T1(onDeviceClick)` it is executing only once.
The if I uncomment `T1{}` and/or `T2("Hello world")` it is only executing only once.

Why in case of calling another composable and passing the callback the composable function is executing 4 times?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a lambda, especially one that captures some state or context, it can cause the child composable to recompose if the lambda identity changes.

You can use the rememberUpdatedState function to ensure the lambda you're passing down has a consistent identity

```
@Composable
fun DeviceListScreen(onDeviceClick: (MyDevice) -> Unit){
    val rememberedCallback = rememberUpdatedState(onDeviceClick)
    T1 { device -> rememberedCallback.value(device) }
}
```